# excel aggregate function works for quartile, but not for average or median

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do simple aggregate functions with the usual conditions.  It works with quartile etc, but not average, median.  What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: To use the array syntax, you need to use a function number of 14 or higher. The lower numbers use the reference syntax, and your conditional argument is an array.

Comment: How would I do average then? Well, there's averageif, but there are 12 other handy functions in there

Comment: You can't do it with `AGGREGATE`. Depending on your version of excel, in order to apply the conditions, you could use `SUMPRODUCT` or, if you have O365, I'd use `FILTER`